# A suitable algorithm to change strings to zero strings

Tags: algorithms

I found a programming exercise I couldn't solve. Namely, I have been given a long binary string and a fixed set of operations. Here, an operation means that it takes a substring and transforms its bits $b_i$ to $1-b_i$. Also, indexed are modulo $n$ so if I apply the transform to the end of the string, also the first bits changes. For example, if a substring is 1010111001 then it becomes 0101000110.

What would be an algorithm to compute what is the minimum number of operations I need to transform a given binary string to 000...00, if the length of the substring is fixed? I heard once that one might apply Gauss–Jordan but I was unable to find the idea how to apply it.

Comment: It might not be possible. For instance, if the original string is $1000\cdots 000$ and the substring length is $2$.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you can take any substring: bits $b_{i}b_{i+1}...b_{j}$ and switch them?  And you actually want to compute the minimum? not just get bounds on the minimum?

Comment: I meant that for a string of length $n$ I can take an arbitrary starting position but the length of the string is fixed.